# Wordpress - get posts by tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey im a newbi to Wordpress.

My Situation:

On my Landingpage i need to click on a tag (for example: cars), this should get me to an other page with all related posts with the tag cars. Is there any function in Wordpress that retrieve posts by tags? I just found a function that return me tags from a post.

Should i need a specific plugin? And if yes, i be not able to modify the plugin output, because if i do an update i need to rework the plugin again.

The Function should return the posts from a tag without any html (just the Objects or something i can handle in my code).

I hope you understand what i need and you have constructive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code :

```
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'cooking' ) );
 /**Or By Tag Id**/
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag_id' => 13 ) );
```

Hope that will work for you

Comment: i really appreciate your answer. Thanks! now im playing around to get the content from the object im struggling with this right now: $query->post_content; how can i retrieve the post ? But thanks man that helps me alot

Comment: I got it , i ahbe done $query->post->post_content;